# Ajax page refresh after specified time given in fadeIn

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I would like to refresh the same page after running the success function. The page must be refreshed after the specified time given in fadeIn function. Is is possible?
This is my success function:

```
success: function(result){
            $('#agencyForm').trigger('reset');
            if(result == '1'){
             $('#approvalmessagedisplay').html('<span style="color:green;">Request is updated successfully</span>').fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: you can use setTimeOut().

Comment: don't know how and where to put setTimeOut()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
success: function(result){
            $('#agencyForm').trigger('reset');
            if(result == '1'){
             $('#approvalmessagedisplay').html('<span style="color:green;">Request is updated successfully</span>').fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
             setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
            }

function myFunction(){
   //some statement
   //will run after 3 sec
   location.reload(); 
}
```

Comment: This works for me now. Thank you
$('#approvalmessagedisplay').html('<span style="color:green;">Request is updated successfully</span>');
                 setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload() }, 3000);